# Django: standard location/conventions for data import scripts?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a number of Django projects, and in most of them, I have initial data to import.

This data isn't neat JSON, as shown in the [fixture examples in the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) - it tends to be messy Excel or CSV files. The scripts tend to look like the following snippet, and I just run them as standalone Python, because I don't know any better:

```
import sys
from django.core.management import setup_environ
sys.path.append(LOCATION OF YOUR DJANGO PROJECTS, EX: 'C:\django')
from mysite import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from PROJECT_NAME.APP_NAME.models import MODEL_NAME

import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(COMPLETE PATH TO YOUR DATA, EX: "C:/django/mysite/restaurants.csv"), dialect='excel')

for row in reader:
   COLUMN_ONE_TITLE = row[0]
   COLUMN_TWO_TITLE = row[1]

   MODEL_NAME.objects.get_or_create(MY_FIRST_COLUMN=COLUMN_ONE_TITLE, MY_SECOND_COLUMN=COLUMN_TWO_TITLE)
```

I feel that when I commit these projects to GitHub or send them to the client or whatever, I should include the import scripts. They're an important part of the project.

Is there a standard way, in Django, to store the import scripts  that I've written to import this data?

Where in the project should they sit? Should I be using management commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like putting them in management commands - that way when someone else works on the project, the commands are where they're expected to be by someone who wasn't familiar with the choices being made during initial development.

Answer (score 1):

Django supports [pluggable](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#serialization-modules) [serialization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) modules. If you can arrange your CSV formats to work as a deserializer, you can use the regular loaddata command.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put all that code in a utility function? so your views.py would have `from utils import csv_import` or something like that. That way your views can programmatically use that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest what Martin or Luke suggested.

But if that won't work for you for some reason, then putting the script right in the root of the git project makes sense. Note, I did not suggest putting it in the root of the django project (though, frankly, that isn't a wrong idea either), but I'm suggesting that the django project be a sub folder of the git repo for the very reason that you can put these helper files somewhere that's not clogging up the django project.